# Triggering a gitlab pipeline ONLY for merge requests that are actually merged

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I'm trying to trigger a gitlab pipeline only after the merge request is actually merged, only for merge requests, and only if it comes from the 'Develpment' branch.

For that I'm using this rule:

```
rules:
        - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "Production"'
          when: manual
        - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_EVENT_TYPE == "merged_result" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "Development"'
          when: on_success
```

However, it seems to be running on any commit to the branch Development...

Comment: Were you able to find the solution